# Operator precedence of ++ and &&

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
int a=0,b=5;
int c=a&&++b;
cout<<b;
```

When I run this snippet, the output value is `5`.

From my understanding, `++` has a greater operator precedence, and so shouldn't `++b` be evaluated before the `&&` leading to the value of `b` to be `6`?

Why does the value in `b` not get incremented? Is it because I misunderstood the precedence or some other feature?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand what operator precedence means in the language. It does not define order of evaluation but rather how expression syntaxically parsed.

Let's look into expression:

```
*ptr++ = b + c / d;
```

operator precedence means that it compiled as:

```
( *(ptr++) ) = ( b + ( c / d ) );
```

not:

```
( *( (ptr++) = b ) + c ) / d;
```

or something like this. But it does not define in which order they evaluated directly.

So back to original:

```
( *(ptr++) ) = ( b + ( c / d ) );
```

in this case we have `operator=` which requires output of `operator*` and output of `operator+` so those operators have to be evaluated before assignment, `operator+` requires output of `operator/` so `operator/` has to be evaluated before `operator+` and so on. But because `operator*` has higher precedence than `operator+` does not mean it will be evaluated first in this case. It's up to compiler to decide as there is no direct dependencies between them.

Answer (score 7):

Precedence isn't what matters here.

`&&` does short circuit evaluation, so first its left operand is evaluated. Then if and only if that is non-zero, its right operand is evaluated.

In your case, its left operand is zero, so its right operand isn't evaluated. Thus, `++b` is never evaluated, so the value of `b` isn't changed.